# OS X menu bar terminal drop down

Tags: macos, terminal

Has anyone come across an OS X menu bar app that when clicked, drops down a terminal instance? Or something that simulates this type of behavior?

I'm show I've seen someone have this functionality but extensive searching hasn't revealed anything and can't remember who I saw with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen anything that works when a menu bar button is clicked, but if a terminal that drops down when a key combination is pressed will suffice, [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) and [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/) provide this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. They look exactly like what I was looking for.